# MYSQL inefficient count on large tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with this structure:

```
id(int), aff_id(int)
```

Field `aff_id` is `0` if the user was not affiliated by anybody and he registered directly, or `larger than 0`, if the user was affiliated by some other player and in that case it takes the value of the ID of the affiliate.

```
user #47 was affiliated by user #55, therefore in the database,
we will have this entry: id=47,aff_id=55
```

I want to see how many users did a good job and affiliated/brought in other users (basically I want to see how many users are affiliates). For that I need to go through each user and see if there is anybody that has his user id inside the aff_id field.
I do not want to see how many users have `aff_id > 0`, because that is basic stuff and it would mean how many players were affiliated.

For my requirement, I run this query:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*),
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `aff_id`=`u`.`id`
) AS total_pl 
FROM `users` u 
HAVING total_pl>0
```

Problem is that the query takes around 30 seconds on a database with 2000 entries.

If I try a different way, it takes even more time ... around 40 seconds:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM `users` u 
WHERE u.id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT (`aff_id`) 
  FROM users 
  WHERE aff_id<>0
)
```

What other options do you suggest that I should try for optimisation?

I was thinking to modify the first query to stop counting how many affiliated players does each user have and to find out instead only if each user has 0 affiliated players or at least 1 affiliated player, but there doesnt seem to be any difference.

Comment: Mind adding some indentation to your code? Edit: Never mind, someone else did it *for you*.

Comment: joins are usually more efficient than subqueries

Comment: Do you have indexes on aff_id and id?

Comment: Yes, the id is a primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what about this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d49d9/5)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `aff_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `aff_id`)
VALUES
    (47, 55),
    (48, 0),
    (49, 55),
    (50, 56),
    (51, 56),
    (53, 57)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct aff_id)
FROM users
WHERE aff_id <> 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d49d9/5/0)**:

```
| COUNT(DISTINCT AFF_ID) |
|------------------------|
|                      3 |
```

This will give you what you asked for

*"I want to see how many users did a good job and affiliated/brought in other users (basically I want to see how many users are affiliates)"*

Comment: I see what the OP wanted now.  Just getting the simple number of affiliates that have users?  +1 for figuring that out and providing a simple solution, although I don't see how useful a number like that is without any context to go with it, but maybe the OP has their reasons.

Answer (score 2):

To get a count of the users for each affiliate

It seems you really don't need to use `id` at all.  Why not just

```
SELECT aff_id, count(*) FROM users
WHERE aff_id <> 0 
GROUP BY aff_id
```

If that isn't what you mean, please explain yourself better.

Comment: You'd probably want to add `aff_id` to the select too, and maybe `order by count(*) desc`.

Comment: This is not correct...see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d49d9/2 OP wants to see how many users are affiliates. Not how many affiliates by user

Comment: @PatrickQ, yeah, I forgot to add that in the select.  Thanks.

Comment: I upvote your answer it is really cool :-) take my fiddle to play with query if you need http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f12bdc/2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  COUNT(aff.id) as aff_num
FROM `users` u 
LEFT JOIN `users` aff 
ON u.id = aff.aff_id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY aff_num DESC
HAVING aff_num>0
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f12bdc/1)  it takes 2ms-5ms to execute my query on 65 records.

You can play with more. I am pretty sure that with 2000 records you will never get more than 3s even if your table is not indexed properly.

So I think that my query is pretty fast and I have proof.

Do you have yours?

Comment: This query takes same amount of time as my 1st query, because it counts for each player how many players he brought in (how many players he affiliated).

Comment: if it takes too long, just add `index \`id\`` and `index \`aff_id\`` in your table structure